# Freeze last frame of animation new code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, sdk, freeze

I'm trying to freeze the last frame of an animation.  The following code used to work, however after an update to iOS it no longer works.  How can I write this code so that the last image stays on the screen?

```
animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop2.png"],

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop4.png"],

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop6.png"],

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop8.png"],

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop10.png"],

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop12.png"],

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop14.png"],

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop15.png"], nil];

    animation.animationDuration = .8;
    animation.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [animation startAnimating];
    [self playwatermelondropsound];
    [self.view addSubview:animation];
    animation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop16.png"];
```

Comment: If it doesn't behave in the way you want then how does this code behave?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I spend 40 my minutes to resolve your problem, and it was just so simple:

There are two way you can achieve what you want:

1. Set the image you want on your screen as `default` image.
2. or just do this,

   ```
   //make your last line to first line.  
   animation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop16.png"];
   animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop2.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop4.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop6.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop8.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop10.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop12.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop14.png"],
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop15.png"], nil];

   animation.animationDuration = .8;
   animation.animationRepeatCount = 1;
   [animation startAnimating];
   [self playwatermelondropsound];
   [self.view addSubview:animation];
   ```

And guess what it'll start working, as I have tested it. :)

Comment: I just tried something similar to this and it works.  I put `animation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop16.png"];` right before `[animation startAnimating];`

Comment: @rptwsthi I want to add fadein and fadeout animation to all image file during animation.. how can i do that?.. can you help me

Answer (score 2):

```
[self cleanStance];
NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"jump1.png"],
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"jump2.png"],
                       nil];    
self.player.animationImages = imageArray;
self.player.animationDuration = 0.3;
//self.player.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
[self.view addSubview:self.player];
[self.player startAnimating];


- (void)cleanStance {
[self.player setImage:nil];
self.player.animationImages = nil;
```

}

This is the example to show the image jumping i thick this may help u

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, except when I do it, I usually set the `.image` property of the `UIImageView` *BEFORE* I tell the `UIImageView` to start animating. Also, add `[UIImage imageNamed:@"watermelondrop16.png"]` to the end of your `.animationImages` array. Maybe that will fix your problem. Hope that Helps!