# smooth UIImageView animation for multiple images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have used animation on an `UIImageView` to animate 36 images like this:

```
-(void) kickOffTheAnimation {

    self.imgView.animationImages = imagesArr;

   [self.imgView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
   self.imgView.animationDuration =0.9;

    [self.imgView startAnimating];

}
```

and my`viewDidLoad` method is simply as:

```
NSMutableArray *imagesArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i =0; i<35; i++) {
    [imagesArr addObject:[UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i@2x.png",i]]];
 }

    [self kickOffTheAnimation];
```

However, there is a small glitch, the animation is not smooth when it reaches the final image and repeats the animation from the first image, how can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:**

the exact problem is there is a milliseconds hang happens after reaching img35.png and showing img0.png

Comment: What is the real problem? You don't want it to repeat the animation?

Comment: i don't know why they give me a down vote !!!

Comment: So the down vote is real problem hmm?

Comment: thank you rptwsthi for the up vote from -1 to 0 ... look at Edit above

Comment: You welcome, by the way I didn't upvoted.. :P ;) and don't forget to check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618262/freeze-last-frame-of-animation-new-code/7618405#7618405

Comment: You know, you don't need this line: [self.imgView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];. Per Apple's documentation: "animationRepeatCount
Specifies the number of times to repeat the animation.

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger animationRepeatCount
Discussion
The default value is 0, which specifies to repeat the animation indefinitely.
"

Answer (score 1):

I have sometimes noticed a very small loop delay with a larger in memory image array. It could be that some resource has to be reloaded. I have used `AVPlayer` in repeat mode with better luck for a small movie. An actual movie might also compress better.